# Heroku Login fails

Tags: heroku

I'm getting following error while login to the Heroku using CLI:

```
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: *****@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       connect timeout reached (Excon::Errors::Timeout)
Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:184:in `rescue in block in connect'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:179:in `block in connect'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:167:in `each'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:167:in `connect'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:97:in `connect'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:28:in `initialize'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:9:in `initialize'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:410:in `new'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:410:in `socket'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:122:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:42:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:22:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:265:in `request'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.17/lib/heroku/api.rb:76:in `request'
             /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.17/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in `post_login'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80:in `api_key'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:189:in `ask_for_credentials'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:221:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:84:in `get_credentials'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41:in `login'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:31:in `login'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku login
HTTP Proxy:  http://proxy:8080/
HTTPS Proxy: https://proxy:8080/
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.6.0 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with java... It is an issue with the `heroku` toolbelt.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey is there any workaround possible for this problem?

Comment: `connect timeout reached` probably has something to do with your network. Are you behind a proxy? Try it without the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

From logs:

> This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running

Answer (score 1):

This seems the same error: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/862

Try to run: heroku run bundle

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up

```
> heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: zeke@example.com
Password:
...
```

Authenticating is required to allow both the heroku and git commands to operate.
Note that if you’re behind a firewall that requires use of a proxy to connect with external HTTP/HTTPS services, you can set the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables in your local development environment before running the heroku command.

**Using an HTTP proxy**

If you’re behind a firewall that requires use of a proxy to connect with external HTTP/HTTPS services, you can set the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables in your local developer environment, before running the heroku command.
For example, on a Unix system you could do something like this:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
or
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
$ heroku login
```

On a Windows machine, either set it in the System Properties/Environment Variables, or do it from the terminal:

```
> set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
or
> set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
> heroku login
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I updated my *heroku cli* and everything is working fine. To update your *heroku cli* run: `wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` 
Note: This command is for ubuntu. If you are on another system then refer to the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install